# Optimal pareto in two-person game

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

For what values $x$, $y$ the profile $(D,L)$ is Pareto optimal?

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
& L  & R \\ \hline
U & x,5 & x+2,y  \\
D& 1,-1 & x,0 \\
\end{array}

Is correct $x<1$ ?

I suppose this because $D$ should not be weakly dominated.

And $y<5$ for the same argument.

Is these values enough to answer that $(D,L)$ is Pareto optimal?

Thanks!

Comment: $(x,y) \in \{(a,b)  \mid a<-5, ~ a + b \leq - 2\}$

Comment: clueless.  Could you explain me a little? Thank you.